# python pandas index by time

Tags: time, indexing, pandas

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
"06/09/2013 14:08:34.930","7.2680542849633447","1.6151231744362988","0","0","21","1546964992","15.772567829158248","1577332736","8360","21.400382061280961","0","15","0","685","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","4637","0"
```

the csv includes 1 month daily values (24 hrs)

I have a need to load it to pandas and then get some stats on data (min, max) but I need the data to include data records for all days only working hours (between 8:00 to 18:00)

I am very new to pandas library

Comment: Can you provide some more information and more than a *single* row of your data set?

Answer (score 0):

Load your data:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, index_col=0)
```

Filter your data for working hours from 8:00 to 18:00:

```
work_hours = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f').hour in range(8, 18)
df = df[map(work_hours, df.index)]
```

Get the min and max of the first data column:

```
min, max = df[1].min(), df[1].max()
```

Comment: I would suggest replacing the work_hours lambda and map with `between_time` which is direct and to the point: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html